# Sudden "Protocol error (Page.navigate): Target closed" in Puppeteer-Lambda Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, puppeteer, chromium

I'm encountering a "Protocol error (Page.navigate): Target closed" with Puppeteer in AWS Lambda. This issue started in our production environment after Dec 5th, 12:00pm EST, without any recent changes to the code.

The error was not present initially in our staging environment. However, after re-running our last GitHub action (with no code changes), the same error started occurring in staging, mirroring the production issue.

I'm perplexed by this sudden occurrence of the error in both environments without any code modifications. What could be causing this issue? Are there any specific logs, settings, or configurations within AWS Lambda or Puppeteer that I should examine? Any insights or suggestions on troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.

Tried changing node version, updating chromium, changing args, using puppeteer core.

Code snippet:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-extra';
import stealthPlugin from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth';

const stealth = stealthPlugin();
puppeteer.use(stealth);

(async () => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true, // Set to false if you need a visible browser window
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
        });

        const page = await browser.newPage();

        const userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; LGL84VL Build/NRD90U) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Mobile Safari/537.36';
        await page.setUserAgent(userAgent);

        const url = 'https://example.com'; // Replace with the target URL
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

        // Additional actions on the page...

        await browser.close();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error occurred:', error);
    }
})();
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "scrp",
  "version": "2.4.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node build/main.js",
    "build": "node node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
    "postbuild": "cp -r src/assets build/",
    "dev": "node node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js --files src/main.ts",
    "install": "node node_modules/rimraf/bin.js node_modules/mongoose/index.d.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/vision": "^3.0.1",
    "@sentry/node": "^6.19.7",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^6.19.7",
    "@socket.io/redis-adapter": "^7.1.0",
    "@sparticuz/chromium": "^109.0.5",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1034.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bullmq": "^1.54.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "csvtojson": "^2.0.10",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "ioredis": "^4.28.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.1",
    "mongoose-lean-virtuals": "^0.9.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.16",
    "object-hash": "^2.2.0",
    "okrabyte": "^0.1.1",
    "pending-xhr-puppeteer": "^2.3.3",
    "phone": "^2.4.22",
    "puppeteer": "19.4",
    "puppeteer-extra": "^3.3.6",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha": "^3.6.8",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.11.2",
    "redis": "^4.0.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "socket.io": "^4.0.0",
    "socket.io-emitter": "^3.2.0",
    "spinnies": "^0.5.1",
    "winston": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.114",
    "@types/aws-sdk": "^2.7.0",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/ioredis": "^4.28.1",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.0",
    "@types/object-hash": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/phone": "^2.4.1",
    "@types/rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: @ggorlen It's not bound to any specific site. For any URL we put, the goto method cannot go to any site, as the "Protocol error (Page.navigate): Target closed" error pops up. And regarding a minimal reproducible example, I can run everything locally, and it works. When it's running on the aws-lambda function, the error pops.

Comment: OK, thanks for confirming. Nonetheless, there must be some setting or environment factor that's causing the failure, so full environment details are probably still necessary, even if code isn't (and if code is out of the picture, it's still good to show a simple launch and goto, and explain in the question itself that any site fails).

Comment: I added a code snippet to the main question. Also, is there any environment or settings you would like me to share?

Comment: Whichever ones you can. I'm not that familiar with AWS, just trying to help get it in a state where someone else can tackle it. A package.json would probably be good. Some of these problems are specific to certain Puppeteer versions.

Comment: Thank you, I've just updated the main question with the package.json.

Comment: My guess is website made a change (ie added advertisement) and it exhausting ram so opsys is killing browser. Can you try with 4x ram?

Comment: @nerkn The thing is that it is indifferent to the site. The function can't launch chromium, even before knowing which site it has to go to.

Answer (score 4):

I think I was able to fix it by using a previous version of node. It looks like Amazon released a new node image on December 5th that caused puppeteer and chromium issue: https://gallery.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs. I changed
`FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:18`
to a previous version released ~3 weeks ago:
`FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:18.2023.11.18.01` in my Dockerfile and that seems to fix the problem. Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Verified working on my end, however there is a sudden change on the size of container (which is important to us). Will try other image from their public registry. Thanks!

https://gallery.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs

Comment: Additionally, if you are deploying an image, be sure to not call yum update while building the image, so you don't get the patch which breaks this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I got the very same error and found no proper working solution as of this writing. The culprit is the `npm install` inside `Dockerfile` as it alters the `package-lock.json` file with new versions of puppeteer and its dependencies -- which happens to be faulty. Changing it to `npm ci` **might work** but not on my end for some reason (you can try it on your end).

The old image is working, so what I did is a mere workaround just keep things running - Alter the existing image.

```
# Make sure to backup your working image by creating a new dockerfile with
FROM existing_image

# Once copied, run the existing image
docker run -dt existing_image 

# Check if it's running and grab it's container id
docker ps
# CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND   CREATED              STATUS              
# 643bf857fceb   existing-image   "R"       6 minutes ago        Up 6 minutes

# Shell into it
docker exec -it 643bf857fceb bash

# delete outdated src (note that this is inside the existing image)
rm -rf src

# Apply code changes (note do the command from other terminal)
docker cp src 643bf857fceb:/var/task/

# Open another terminal tab/window, and save the running container you modified
docker commit 643bf857fceb my-new-image

# Inspect to ensure it saved correctly
docker image ls
# REPOSITORY           TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
# existing-image       latest    a7dde5d84fe5   7 minutes ago   888MB
# my-new-image         latest    d57fd15d5a95   2 minutes ago   888MB

# Push my-new-image to aws container registry
docker push xxxx/my-new-image
```

Note that I don't have any dependency update, it is a pure src code logic so this is a suited temporary solution for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: try to change the node version to a specific one, since the update aws did that was killing my new browser in lambda. as @michal k says if you change your current node version for example from 20 18 16 to something like:
public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:18.2023.11.18.01
public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:16.2023.11.18.01
etc it should be working. In my end it worked perfectly

Comment: @alecellis1985 verified working. Thanks for pointing that out. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Same exact Error of @Gio,
dependencies i have that works locally and in an aws server but not lambda function:

```
"puppeteer": "^21.6.0",
"puppeteer-extra": "^3.3.6",
"puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha": "^3.6.8",
"puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.11.2",
```

I have tried moving to puppeteer-core but did not work either.
Will try the image suggestion.
Line that breaks is:

```
import puppeteerExtra from 'puppeteer-extra';
var browser = await puppeteerExtra.launch({ ...options });
```